# Call a simple C++ VS6 function from java

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

i make a simple function in Visual studio 6 this is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)


{
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char __stdcall GetCompanyCode()
{
    return 1;
}
```

i need to call the function GetCompanyCode from java so i used JNA
at first i create Interface in java

```
package javaapplication4;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
/**
 *
 * @author amir
 */
public interface CompanyCode extends Library
{
    public  byte GetCompanyCode();
}
```

then load the dll

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author amir
 */
public class JavaApplication4 
{
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException, FileNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException 
    {
        System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:/");
        CompanyCode Company= (CompanyCode)Native.loadLibrary("CompanyCode", CompanyCode.class);
        byte x=Company.GetCompanyCode();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

i got the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error
>   looking up function 'GetCompanyCode': The specified procedure could
>   not be found.
>
> at com.sun.jna.Function.(Function.java:179)   at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:347)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:327)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.GetCompanyCode(Unknown Source)  at
>   javaapplication4.JavaApplication4.main(JavaApplication4.java:28)
>   C:\Users\amir\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

what should i do?

Comment: `extern "C"` is not C, but C++. It also does not make the function a C function, but only changes the interface (ABI and naming conventions).

Comment: not directly related but you'll run into this next: since you're using __stdcall, you need to extend from `StdCallLibrary`, not `Library`